# Subset the shapefile from Sentinel 2 data in Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, sentinel-2

I am new to Google Earth Engine and I am working with Sentinel-2 data for salinity mapping. I have the shapefile of my Area of interest, I want that to be subsetted from the data. What commands should I need to get this?

Comment: `ee.ImageCollection.filterBounds(geometry)` filters images based on a geometry: https://code.earthengine.google.com/676d229f1fc7e291fe3fa115bf3e2a7f